# Copy files with extension - search subfolders

Tags: filesystems, file-transfer, regex

Copying ttf files from one folder to another using wildcard "**/*ttf", however this is not searching the files in sub-folders as well. How can I copy all the files (present in sub-folders as well) making some change in wild card?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: It's Oracle EL5. However, the wildcard I used was correct and working after resolving few other environmental issues. Thanks all for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Using [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) :

```
shopt -s globstar
cp **/*ttf another_dir
```

Comment: First `*/` is not needed.

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Find is the answer :)

`find [star dir] -type f -name "*ttf" -exec cp {} [destination folder] \+`

See `man find`